# Limit the number of rows and number of characters per row using knockoutJS

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am creating an application using KnockoutJS where I need to limit the number of lines(rows) in a `<textarea>` to 8 and the number of characters per line to 25. I am facing the following issues:

1. Not able to limit the number of lines (rows) to 8.
2. Able to limit the characters per line to 25 but if a key is pressed continuously this functionality also does not work.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
      <!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->
      <textarea data-limit-rows="true" cols="30" rows="9" data-bind="event: {keyup:check}"></textarea>                                      

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>
      <script src="js/script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.check= function(d,e) {
        var maxLength = 25;
        var text = $(e.currentTarget).val(),
        lines = text.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm),
       //maxRows = parseInt($(e.currentTarget).attr("rows")); 
       maxRows=8;
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if (lines[i].length > maxLength) {
                lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, maxLength);
            }
        }

    };
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advice you to use a `ko.computed` with a `read` and `write` function. Data-bind this observable using the `textInput` binding.

The `write` stores the text input in an internal backing field. The `read` transforms and limits the string to meet your requirements.

Note that the `notify: always` extension is important here. When new *raw* input generates the same *computed* input, knockout will not trigger an update and your textarea will not be cleared. By using `notify: always`, you can tell knockout to reset the textarea every time, even if it's to the same value.

```js
function AppViewModel() {
  var MAX_LINES = 4;
  var MAX_LENGTH = 5;
  var rawValue = ko.observable("");
  this.value = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      return rawValue()
        .split("\n")
        .reduce(function(lines, line) {
          if (line.length === 0) {
            lines.push("");
          } 
          
          while(line.length) {
            lines.push(line.slice(0, MAX_LENGTH));
            line = line.slice(MAX_LENGTH, line.length); 
          }

          return lines;
        }, [])
        .slice(0, MAX_LINES)
        .join("\n");
    },
    write: rawValue
  }).extend({"notify": "always"});
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<textarea cols="25" rows="9" data-bind="textInput: value"
          style="font-family: monospace"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks it seems working well :). But is there anyway way to go to the next line when the limit is reached?

Comment: I've included the logic to automatically add a new line when the end of a line is reached. Code is a bit harder to read, might be worth it to refactor. The `map` that returned the first `n` characters is replaced by a `reduce`. This function creates an array of lines by, instead of discarding any overflow characters, injecting a new line. The `if (line.length === 0)` is needed to support user generated empty lines.

Comment: Thanks code works as expected. I have Accepted your answer. As you said logic seems difficult to read.

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much for this snippet. BTW, is there a way to include wordwrapping  feature to this?

Comment: The `while(line.length)` block splits a string in to `x` parts of `y` characters. You can add any logic you like here, including appending an extra "-" at the end of a line if there's a forced line break. I *do* think that, if you have many advanced requirements, you might be better off with a ready-made WYSIWYG editor library.